# What is relationship between cv2.setmousecallback() and cv2.waitkey()

Tags: opencv, python

I am trying to draw a circle in a video frame but I have problem, for example:

```
vid1=cv2.VideoCapture('animal_video.mp4')

if vid1.isOpened():
    print('is opened')

def mousedf(event,x,y,flags,params):
    global nx,ny
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        nx,ny=x,y
    if flags & cv2.EVENT_FLAG_LBUTTON:
        radius=int(math.sqrt((x-nx)**2+(y-ny)**2))
        cv2.circle(frame,(nx,ny),radius,(0,0,200),3)



cv2.namedWindow('frame')
cv2.setMouseCallback('frame',mousedf)

while True:
    ret,frame=vid1.read()
    if not ret:
        print('Not enough Frame, will break')
        break
    k=cv2.waitKey(30)
    if k == 27:
        break
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

vid1.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

In the above code, I **can** see the circle in each frame.
However, if I change the order of `cv2.imshow()` and `cv2.waitkey()`,
I **cannot** see the circle.

```
while True:
    ret,frame=vid1.read()
    if not ret:
        print('Not enough Frame, will break')
        break
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    k=cv2.waitKey(30)
    if k == 27:
        break
```

I would like to know the reason of the problem, and the relationship between `cv2.setMouseCallback()` and `cv2.waitkey()`.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, when a movie is passing images in time and In fact, a video is the passage of images in time and updates the `cv2.waitKey(*time*)` of different sequences with the given time.

If you use this code, you will be given the opportunity to update the new image after each run and after the show by `cv2.imshow('frame', frame)`

```
while True:
    ret,frame=vid1.read()
    if not ret:
        print('Not enough Frame, will break')
        break

    k=cv2.waitKey(30)  --->stop image 
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame) --->show update image
    if k == 27:
        break
```